# Why Windows text files encoding crash after I open them in Linux system?

Tags: text-processing, windows, text-formatting, character-encoding, text

I use Debian and sometimes I need to mount Windows disks because I want to read some *.txt file from Windows. Sometimes it's okay, but sometimes after I edit or read file using Debian system and then reboot to Windows and try to open file instead of

```
This is text in my txt file.
```

I see

```
This is td�T$(�b.U�D$$�X��B�D$,�@��Z�Eȃ��D$�D$DZ��
```

I use mousepad as my Debian editor and default notepad for Windows.
Is there any way to restore text ? How to fix this so next time this do not happen ?

Comment: Could you please upload a sample file somewhere? E.g. zippyshare?

Comment: This is particularly odd because part of the file is still readable, part of it is scrambled.  Usually for encoding issues you see either the odd messed up character (eg UTF8 to Latin1) or the entire file transposed into something incomprehensible (eg Latin1 to UTF16).  Half and half is just weird.  I'd like to see a 'hexdump -c' to show what bytes exactly are changing.

Answer (score 0):

Test your crashing file with the file-command in Linux and compare it with non-crashing files.

Most probable, there is a mismatch in file-encoding, and maybe some unwanted auto-detection involved.

Linux offers UTF-8 on most systems since 20 years, and you shouldn't change that. Windows has been later to the party, but more recent installations should use utf-8 by default, too.

Some editors may carry an old default setting like CP850 or ISO-LATIN-x, with x being a number or something else..

To avoid ambiguity, there have been movements, to put a BOM in the beginning of a file, which makes the problem even worse, because, for example, shell scripts in Linux use a Shebang (like `#!/bin/bash`) at the beginning and don't accept a BOM at all.

If possible, set all your tools to UTF-8 and convert older files, where possible (linux program: iconv).

With

```
file clean-and-easy.txt 
file crashing.txt
```

you should first look, whether the file command reports something, like `ascii-text with BOM` or `UTF-8 Unicode text`.